# Chrome: JavaScript window.open to be Save-able

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Imagine a FTP client written in HTML and JavaScript. This part works. But it would be nice if user can "copy the listing" into clipboard. Turns out that clipboard stuff is not so easy in JS (besides, listings can be huge). So better is to pop up a window with the generated listing, then user can chose to Copy'Paste, or Save the page to disk.

Currently I do:

```
    my_window = window.open("", "Copy List");
    my_window.document.write('<pre>\n'+string+'</pre>');
    my_window.document.close();
```

Which works. I get a new tab, and the listing I have generated in "string" displays nicely.

But Chrome disables/greyes-out the "Save Page" option. It would be nice if user can save the page (html or txt). What magic is required to open a window/tab and let them save the content?

Since we use WebSockets (key1/key2) this only works in Chrome, no other browsers needed.

Comment: Pretty much every browser supports web sockets; you're going to need a better excuse than that to drop cross-browser support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: It is more about the version of protocol. Since I implemented the WebSocket port on the FXP.One engine for the JS code to talk to, I only implemented the new protocol, which uses Sec-WebSocket-Key and Sec-WebSocket-Accept. Currently (at least, when we started the code in Dec) that meant only Chrome. All other browsers used key1/key2, or, was disabled. I could have implemented the old protocol as well, but as it was being phased out, I felt waiting was easier.

Comment: I tested Firefox again, still old protocol. But Firefox-Beta5 has them updated, and does indeed work nicely with FXP.One. So, I guess if you run the beta, a solution for two browsers would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Way after the fact but you can use a data URI for this:

`window.open("data:text/plain;base64,"+btoa(theCode))`

Comment: [Deprecated](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/chrome-60-deprecations#remove_content-initiated_top_frame_navigations_to_data_urls) by all browsers.