# Saving a document when opened with window.open in chrome

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with opening a new window with javascript. I have HTML code in a var called "theCode";

```
var j = window.open('')
j.document.write(theCode);
j.document.close();
```

The following code works fine, but in chrome i can't save the new document or view the source code(the options are disabled). In firefox it's fine. Is there any workaround in chrome for this?

Comment: `window.open('')` opens the `about:blank` page in Chrome. Unless there is a way to change that, I guess you won't be able to do what you want.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9612045/139010

Comment: That dub does not have a concreet answer. @acdcjunior i am building a newsletter generator, i want the complete newsletter to be opened in a new tab so that u can save it straight away

Comment: I see what you mean. So the newsletter (that will be saved) is generated by javascript?

Comment: Yeah, everything is generated with JavaScript

Comment: Maybe you could deploy a HTML page that prints what it got in the get parameters and open that page sending the text in those parameters. Seems like there is no other way. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pp75t/ - it can fool chrome to enable "Save as", but when you try it, it never works. Once you use `document.write()` the page can never be saved (even though the Save As is enabled).

Comment: Can someone point me to specs for the disabled Save As function? The answer on this dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416646/javascript-popup-chrome-save-as-deactivated-why also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Several months after the fact but I'm pretty sure you can use a data URI for this:

window.open("data:text/html;base64,"+btoa(theCode))

Comment: And several years later: you can't. It generates an empty page